# How do I search for a variable in a column and then print out all the rows that contain the number in a csv file with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm making a program that checks for a number in a CSV and then prints out the entire row. The 4th one is the number. Here is what I tried:

```
 with open('Info.csv', 'r') as csv_file
 if 'View C' in choice:
        read = csv.reader(csv_file)
        view = str(input("Enter Number: "))
        for column in read:
            if view == column[3]:
                print(row)
```

The csv file is structured like this:

```
John,Smith,London,131390890
Bob,Builder,Moscow,123123132
Dab,God,LA,131390890
```

I want the program to be like this:

Input:

```
123123132
```

Output:

```
Bob,Builder,Moscow,123123132,
```

It also needs to be able to do this:

Input:

```
131390890
```

Output:

```
John,Smith,London,131390890,
Dab,God,LA,131390890,
```

Thank you!

Btw using Python 3...

Comment: And your code does not do what you want? How? Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: In your code, what are `choice` and `row`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension. To find the rows that have the number you are looking for, read the entire file, appending each line to a list named `content`. Then:

```
result = [i for i in content if i[-1] == 'your_number']
```

This way, the variable `result` will contain N rows, each having the last column matching your number

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc` to subset the DataFrame based on a value in a column. Assuming that the name of the columns is `whichever_column_your_number_exists` and the value you are looking for is `view`. Also ensure that the datatype of the column is same as the value `view` that you are searching for.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Info.csv') #Read your CSV file
your_df = df.loc[df['whichever_column_your_number_exists'] == view] #Assuming view is str type
```

And then iterate over each row of your new DataFrame `yourdf` and print value in each of the columns.

```
for row in your_df.index:
    print(df.at[row, column1_name], df.at[row, column2_name], df.at[row, column3_name], df.at[row, column4_name]
```

Comment: Consider including a short description of your solution to help others understand your code and how it solves the posted question.

Comment: @HenryWoody Sorry man. I added it now. I was stuck answering another question.